# Verificar si un valor existe en un Arreglo Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Bunas tardes acudo a ustedes debido a que tengo problemas al validar si un campo existe en un arreglo lo detallo a continuacion:
tengo 2 arreglos:

```
1.- respuestas=[
            {idPregunta:1,idSeccion:1,respuesta:true}
            {idPregunta:2,idSeccion:1,respuesta:false}
            {idPregunta:3,idSeccion:1,respuesta:malo}
           ]
2.- preguntas=[
               {idPregunta:1,idSeccion:1}
               {idPregunta:2,idSeccion:1}
               {idPregunta:3,idSeccion:1}
               {idPregunta:4,idSeccion:1}
            ]
```

quisiera obtener que preguntas no estan en el objeto de respuestas validando el "idPregunta" y el "idSeccion"
He buscando en internet y encuentro ejemplos con indexof pero no logro manejar la validacion por idPregunta y idSeccion
espero me puedan ayudar les agradeceria muchisimo

Answer (score 1):

La opcion mas sencilla es iterar por todas las respuestas y buscar que no este en las preguntas.
te puedes values de los metodos `Array.filter` y `Array.some` para estos fines, abajo tienes un codigo que puedes ejecutar y ver el resultado asi como entender la logica.

Disfrutalo y cualquier duda no lo pienses dos veces para hacer un comentario

```js
const respuestas=[
            {idPregunta:1,idSeccion:1,respuesta:true},
            {idPregunta:2,idSeccion:1,respuesta:false},
            {idPregunta:3,idSeccion:1,respuesta:"malo"},
           ];
const preguntas=[
               {idPregunta:1,idSeccion:1},
               {idPregunta:2,idSeccion:1},
               {idPregunta:3,idSeccion:1},
               {idPregunta:4,idSeccion:1},
            ];
const result = preguntas.filter(p=>!respuestas.some(r=>r.idPregunta===p.idPregunta && r.idSeccion===p.idSeccion));

document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, null, 4) +
        '</pre>';
```